# How to animate layer shadowOpacity?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, quartz-graphics

I have a view on which I've set the layerOpacity to 1.

```
    theView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
```

This looks fine when the view is farther down the screen.  When I move this view up to be flush with another view that has a shadow, they don't look good.  Is there a way I can animate the `shadowOpacity` on my layer to be 0?  I tried using an animation block but it seems as if this property is not animatable.

[image]

**EDIT:** Request for code that doesn't work:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    splitView2.layer.shadowOpacity = 0;}
                 completion:NULL];
```

Comment: From Apple's docs: "`@property float shadowOpacity` Specifies the opacity of the receiver’s shadow. **Animatable**." Can you post some code where that doesn't work?

Comment: doesn't work in UIView animateWithDuration

Comment: @JoeBlow: Correct, that's why I wrote that the code I posted doesn't work. You'll have to use Core Animation directly, since `UIView` doesn't provide an implicit animation for it.

Comment: hi Sudo! To be clear, notice @Costique 's comment: I was replying to that comment.  Cheers!  Thanks for asking this handy question, which resulted in the good answer below.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

This will work properly:

```
#import <QuartzCore/CAAnimation.h>

CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowOpacity"];
anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
anim.duration = 1.0;
[vv.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"shadowOpacity"];
vv.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;
```

**For Swift 3.0:**

```
 let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "shadowOpacity")
 animation.fromValue = layer.shadowOpacity
 animation.toValue = 0.0
 animation.duration = 1.0
 view.layer.add(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)
 view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
```

Comment: if you not set the vv.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0; at the last line, the animation will be done but after that it will jump back to the old layer

Comment: If you want to animate the shadow on rather than off, these two pieces are important: `anim.removedOnCompletion = NO; anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;`

Comment: @moby Thanks for your comment.  That is an essential point to getting this answer to work.

Comment: Can the code snippet be updated with where `anim.removeOnCompletion` should go?

Comment: Important note: animations implemented via this method might not run at a reduced speed when "Debug > Slow Animations" is enabled in the iOS simulator. This one sent me off in the weeds for quite some time.

Specifically, I thought I had set my animation up incorrectly because my custom view transition was running at reduced speed, but my CABasic animation ran at full speed.

Answer (score 5):

I've put above code in a little extension of UIView:

```
extension UIView {

func animateLayer<Value>(_ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<CALayer, Value>, to value:Value, duration: CFTimeInterval) {

    let keyString = NSExpression(forKeyPath: keyPath).keyPath
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: keyString)
    animation.fromValue = self.layer[keyPath: keyPath]
    animation.toValue = value
    animation.duration = duration
    self.layer.add(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)
    var thelayer = layer
    thelayer[keyPath: keyPath] = value
}
}
```

Usage like:

```
animateLayer(\.shadowOffset, to: CGSize(width: 3, height: 3), duration:1)
animateLayer(\.shadowOpacity, to: 0.4, duration: 1)
```

It's not thoroughly tested. but worked for me.
(Also posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45564192/how-to-use-swift-4-keypath-in-cashapelayer-animation/59211947#59211947))

Answer (score 2):

The below code work for me

1)Add QuartzCore frame work
2)Import  QuartzCore frame work

Add the following Code in the required place

```
UIImageView * glowimageview = [[[UIImageView alloc]init]autorelease];
    [glowimageview setFrame:CGRectMake(500,400,200,200)];
    [glowimageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"144.png"]];
    [sender addSubview:glowimageview];

    glowimageview.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    glowimageview.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
    glowimageview.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
    glowimageview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;

    CABasicAnimation *shadowAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowOpacity"];
    shadowAnimation.duration=1.0;
    shadowAnimation.repeatCount=HUGE_VALF;
    shadowAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
    shadowAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    shadowAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
    [glowimageview.layer addAnimation:shadowAnimation forKey:@"shadowOpacity"];
```

It will works. Change the format of the code as per your requirement

Answer (score 2):

Here's a material design like take on some of the above with animations
It's also available here as framework through Carthage https://github.com/sevenapps/SVNMaterialButton

```
public init(frame: CGRect, color: UIColor) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor = color
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 8
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 8.0, height: 8.0)
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("This class is not set up to be instaciated with coder use init(frame) instead")
}

public override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height / 4
}

public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.animate(to: 0.5, and: CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0), with: 0.5)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}

public override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.animate(to: 0.8, and: CGSize(width: 8.0, height: 8.0), with: 0.5)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}

private func animate(to opacity: Double, and offset: CGSize, with duration: Double){
    CATransaction.begin()
    let opacityAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "shadowOpacity")
    opacityAnimation.toValue = opacity
    opacityAnimation.duration = duration
    opacityAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
    opacityAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth
    opacityAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

    let offsetAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "shadowOffset")
    offsetAnimation.toValue = offset
    offsetAnimation.duration = duration
    offsetAnimation.timingFunction = opacityAnimation.timingFunction
    offsetAnimation.fillMode = opacityAnimation.fillMode
    offsetAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

    self.layer.add(offsetAnimation, forKey: offsetAnimation.keyPath!)
    self.layer.add(opacityAnimation, forKey: opacityAnimation.keyPath!)
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```