# How to use Swift 4 KeyPath in CAShapeLayer animation

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

If I write Swift 3 code it would look like this:

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CAShapeLayer.path))
```

But I tried to use Swift 4 new syntax for keyPath and I got:

```
let keyPath = \CAShapeLayer.path
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: keyPath) // error line
```

> **> Error**: Cannot convert value of type 'ReferenceWritableKeyPath' to expected argument type 'String?'

How can I use key path in this situation with swift 4?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As for now `CABasicAnimation` still uses the old `String` keyPaths so you should still use `#keyPath(CAShapeLayer.path)` even though you are using Swift 4.

Apple will probably update all it's APIs in the future to make use of these safer key path references. But for now you are stuck with "unsafe" Strings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use swift keypaths.
Like:

```
extension UIView {

func animateLayer<Value>(_ keyPath: WritableKeyPath<CALayer, Value>, to value:Value, duration: CFTimeInterval) {

    let keyString = NSExpression(forKeyPath: keyPath).keyPath
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: keyString)
    animation.fromValue = self.layer[keyPath: keyPath]
    animation.toValue = value
    animation.duration = duration
    self.layer.add(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)
    var thelayer = layer
    thelayer[keyPath: keyPath] = value
}
}
```

Usage like:

```
animateLayer(\.shadowOffset, to: CGSize(width: 3, height: 3), duration:1)
animateLayer(\.shadowOpacity, to: 0.4, duration: 1)
```

It's not thoroughly tested. but worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

For Swift 5 you can use something similar to this:

```
let ba: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CAEmitterLayer.emitterPosition))
ba.fromValue = topMid
ba.toValue = topMid.offsetBy(dx: dx, dy: dy)
ba.duration = 6
ba.autoreverses = true
ba.repeatCount = .infinity
snowflakeEmitterLayer.add(ba, forKey: nil)
```

Comment: How is this answer different from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45564535/865175?