# Animate shadow properties

Tags: ios, swift

I want to animate shadow properties for a view. Initially I tried:

```
func animateIn(delay: TimeInterval = 0) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: delay, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
            self.shadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            self.shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 15, height: 15)
            self.shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 20
            self.shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

which doesnt work given that UIView.animate doesnt work with layers.

I tested the following post ([How to animate layer shadowOpacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502569/how-to-animate-layer-shadowopacity)), but it only specifies how to animate the shadow Opacity. Is there any way to animate all my shadow properties like I would with an animation blocl?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, you just create multiple `CABasicAnimation`s for all the property changes and then you can use `CAAnimationGroup`

So let say you have 2 `CABasicAnimation` animations like:

```
let shadownOpacityAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "shadowOpacity")
...
let shadowRadiusAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "shadowRadius")
...
```

Then you can add them using `CAAnimationGroup`

```
let group = CAAnimationGroup()
group.duration = 0.2
group.repeatCount = 1
group.autoreverses = false
group.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
group.animations = [shadownOpacityAnimation, shadowRadiusAnimation]
layer.add(group, forKey: "allAnimations")
```

You can read more about it in this answer:

[How can I create an CABasicAnimation for multiple properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938223/how-can-i-create-an-cabasicanimation-for-multiple-properties)

Comment: I did it but I don't know why it doesn't work for me